# Are there limitations when using unsafe code in .NET?

Tags: .net, unsafe, restrictions

I see the allow unsafe code option in .NET. Only one of my apps have it set so i can copy an image to a bitmap quickly.

Will there be limitations now that i checked off that box? mono seems to run it fine on linux. I dont see any problems so far.

Comment: "so i can copy an image to a bitmap quickly." - do you really need to resort to unsafe?

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: I dont see any other way to use IntPtr which is the only var it gives me to access the bitamp

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563038/fast-work-with-bitmaps-in-c

Answer (score 3):

A possible limitation is that your code can run only in full trust.

Comment: What do you mean by full trust? when i run the exe on a strange comp it runs fine on a restricted user.

Comment: It means that it requires Full Trust permission which most hosting providers don't give. Of course if you are running this on a client computer where you have access this will be no problem at all for you. But I wouldn't make a reusable library component which you give to people out of this.