# How can I store my matrix in a picture Box in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a  256x256 matrix and each element of the matrix: `myMatrix[i,j] // represents a pixel`
How can I store my matrix in a picture Box in C#?

Comment: You can create a Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(256,256) and do a double loop if SetPixel. Then pbox.Image = bmp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method is to create a bitmap of equal size and use [SetPixel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.setpixel?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) for each x,y value.

You will need some kind of transform between the values in the matrix and the color values in the image. If your values is in [0,255] you can just clamp the values. Otherwise the simplest method would be to use linear interpolation between min and max:

```
var i = (byte)((matrixValue - matrixMinValue) * 255 / (matrixMinValue - matrixMinValue)) 
var color  = Color.FromArgb(i,i,i);
myBitmap.SetPixel(x, y, color)
```

Set the bitmap to the `pictureBox.Image` property and you should be good to go.

SetPixel should be adequate for a small image that is set infrequently. If you need higher performance you can look at [using pointers to copy data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563038/fast-work-with-bitmaps-in-c-sharp).

Comment: @noob234 you probably have a column-major order matrix. Images are usually row-major. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order