# How to set pixels from original image to a new image?

Tags: c#, winforms

usage

```
public UserControlTester()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            GetSetPixelsRandom();
        }
```

code

```
private void GetSetPixelsRandom()
        {
            Bitmap img = new Bitmap(@"d:\\downloaded images\\test.gif");
            for (int i = 0; i < img.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < img.Height; j++)
                {
                    Color pixel = img.GetPixel(i, j);
                    pixels.Add(pixel);
                }
            }

            Bitmap img1 = new Bitmap(512,512);

            for (int i = 0; i < img1.Width; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < img1.Height; j++)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < pixels.Count; c++)
                    {
                        img1.SetPixel(i, j, pixels[c]);
                    }
                }
            }

            img1.Save(@"d:\\downloaded images\\test3.gif");
        }
```

Not sure if this is the right way.  the inner loop with the variable c take a lot of time because there are more then 290,000 pixels.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fast work with Bitmaps in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563038/fast-work-with-bitmaps-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to resize the image, this can be done easily. The `Bitmap` [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#System_Drawing_Bitmap__ctor_System_Drawing_Image_System_Drawing_Size_) has rescaling build in:

```cs
Bitmap img = new Bitmap(@"d:\\downloaded images\\test.gif");
Bitmap img1 = new Bitmap(img, new Size(512, 512));
img1.Save(@"d:\\downloaded images\\test3.gif");
```

If you do not want to resize but indeed take random pixels take a look at what at [MickyD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/585968/mickyd) mentioned.

Note that in your provided example every pixel in the new image is effectively set to the last pixel in the `pixels` list because you loop over every pixel in `pixels` for every pixel in the new image.